# broken image path instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using instafeed.js for instagram photos, everything is working but the images are broken. When i click on one it takes me to the correct instagram page but the images themselves are just broken. Any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 143928822,
    accessToken: '143928822.5b9e1e6.36ad47c3abaf4c9bb813748ce8072a12',
    sortBy: "most-recent 
});
userFeed.run();
</script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you look at the Network tab of the developer console, are you getting 404 NotFound responses when your browser attempts to retrieve the image resources? Or is it some other response code?

Comment: I added another screen shot I have never been in that section of dev tools so is that what you where talking about?

Comment: Hmm... I'm more familiar with chrome's dev tools. Safari doesn't appear to be displaying that information. If you reload the page with that tab open, does it look different? Or do they have multiple GET requests on the left there?

Comment: well i uploaded the files to a server http://nickshanekearney.com/insta/insta.html but it seems all it needed was to actuly be on a server. it works live, just not on my local machine....THANKS FOR HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `useHttp: true` to your settings:

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: 143928822,
  accessToken: 'xxxxxx',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  useHttp: true
});
userFeed.run();
```

---

This setting is required if you are viewing your HTML file directly from your file system.

You can tell if this is the case by looking at your address bar. If it begins with `file://`, you are using your file system.

If you're curious as to why that is required, check out Paul Irish's article on [the protocol relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this is not a complete solution, only a recommendation on how to get started solving the problem.

---

When you request a web page in your browser, a few things happen.

1. Your browser issues a GET request to the target
2. The target server responds with some [HTTP response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and potentially some html to display
3. Your browser looks through that html and finds references to various other *resources**
4. Your browser issues GET requests for all those resources
5. the servers that those resources are on respond with more response codes and potentially the requested resources

If your browser isn't displaying the images, it's because the server that holds them isn't giving them to you. This could be for many reasons including:

- 404 - the resource couldn't be found
- 500 - the server had some error occur
- 403 - you're not allowed to access the image for some reason.

If you can figure out what response code you're getting for the resources, you'll have something to work with.

---

*images, videos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add `resolution: 'low_resolution'` to your settings. My settings has been set to `standard_resolution` and it was firing 404 errors on the pages I was hosting and 5xx error on the instagram cdn. So the setting should be as following:

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: 143928822,
  accessToken: 'xxxxxx',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  resolution: 'low_resolution'
});
userFeed.run();
```

This method will find low res images for the cdn and display those. Play around with the standard and thumbnail images. This is by no means a fix but at least it will display your images from their cdn instead of hosting it.